# My Jmeter Webdriver sampler test is too heavy on my machine. I'm planning to use selenium grid, with selenium grid ,will it make my test more lighter?

Tags: performance, selenium, jmeter, webdriver, selenium-grid

My Jmeter Webdriver sampler test is too heavy on my machine. I'm planning to use selenium grid, with selenium grid ,will it make my test more lighter? As of the moment while running my test on gui and non gui mode I'm encountering a web driver timeout , connection timeout, and an out of memory error. Will this approach help?

Comment: do you encounter these errors if your script is run with just 1 target?  Make sure that your script will work with that first.  the general nature of the problems you've mentioned could be due to problems in your script, rather than with the specs of your machine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to read [WebDriver Sampler's documentation](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/)?

> Note: It is NOT the intention of this project to replace the [HTTP Samplers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) included in [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/). Rather it is meant to compliment them by measuring the end user load time.

You should not be creating the main load using WebDriver Samplers, 99.99999% of the virtual users should be simulated on [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) protocol level, WebDriver Sampler could be used only for specific use cases like OAuth login, checking client side performance, etc.

Check out [How to make JMeter behave more like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) article to learn how to properly setup JMeter for web applications testing so it would generate the same network footprint as the real user using the real browser.

If your have a form of a strict requirement to use the real browsers - consider switching to [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) as in case of Selenium Grid you will not be able to collect samplers execution metrics precisely.